# Change user templates path in Word 2007

Tags: microsoft-office-2007

I can not change the **User Templates** path in "File location...".

It simply refuses to change to anything different.
My goal is to set the path to a templates folder on the server e.g \myserver\folder\templates.
Although, choosing a different local path does not work either. It simply does not respond/react and keeps the default path.

Can you offer any assistance?

[image]

(The screenshot is not from a client-computer of mine. I live in Denmark. I did not want to confuse you with danish screenshots.)

Some info:

Client computers:

- Windows XP SP3
- Microsoft Office 2007 OEM (Updated to SP2)

The problem goes for all my client computers. I work for a small sized company with 30 computers. We are slowly upgrading them to Office 2007 from Office 2003 - and this is one of the problems I am facing. So far, the only computers with Office 2007 is completely new computers with Microsoft Office 2007 OEM (updated to SP2). This will only happen for our really old computers though. The others will simply just receive an upgrade-license...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a group policy setting that forces the template folder to a particular location?

Comment: Thanks, this was it! Appearently it has added some group policies by default

Comment: The server I mean

Answer (score 0):

I can set this just fine, both to a local folder on my computer and to a server on my LAN. I've got Word 2007 OEM running on Windows XP SP2. My your screenshot, you seem to be running Vista, so maybe that's part of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Have you read this article? http://support.microsoft.com/kb/924460

I can change mine no worries on the same OS (Vista)...what are you trying to change it to?  Does it accept any other folder on your C drive?

Comment: No it accepts no other folders, at all. Locally (C:\\) nor the intranet (\\something). Nothing changes when I have selected a new path and click: OK. The path in the File Locations window simply stays the same

Comment: Honestly, I don't know then.  What about the other settings like "Documents", can you change those?  Is this person an administrator? I don't see anything saying you would need admin rights, but just in case.

Comment: The user has administrator rights on the local computer, also yes, I can change the other settings like documents. It is more than strange!

Answer (score 0):

change the path in the registry

open regedit and search for the value:
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Office\12.0\Common\General
Create UserTemplates
and then set it to your preffered location